# Is there an erlang null statement

Tags: null, erlang

Does erlang has null statement like 'pass' in python or ';' in C ?
Sometimes I want to test the code without the pain of killing all the processes, cleaning the ets tables and starts all over.

```
try
    ets:new(TableName,[options])
catch
    % if the ets table has been initialized in the earlier test.
    error:badarg->
        % I want an empty statement instead of an ugly io:format
        io:format("")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The atom `ok` is often used for that:

```
try
    ets:new(TableName,[options])
catch
    % if the ets table has been initialized in the earlier test.
    error:badarg->
        ok
end.
```

It's not strictly speaking a "null statement", since it does have an effect: it becomes the return value of the expression.  For example, the above `try` expression will return an ETS table id if table creation succeeds, and the atom `ok` if it fails.  Of course, as long as you are ignoring the return value, that doesn't matter.

**EDIT:** You need to do this as there are no statements in Erlang, everything is an expression and returns a value.

Comment: And note that `io:format/1` returns `ok`, so you're getting the exact same effect without the pointless function call.